# How can I configure @GeneratedValue from JPA 2.0 in my situation

Tags: java, entity, jpa-2.0

I have a peculiar situation, I have an entity mapped with **@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)**, I insert multiples values into my table with a task, working fine.

The situation is, I have a legacy system that populate the same table using a generated value from a sequence table (**GenerationType.TABLE**), it works fine too.

When I need to run my task, it will populate auto-incrementing the id (e.g. 1,2,3,4,5,6,7), after that the sequence table is updated, then the legacy system insert a new row (e.g. id = 8).

The problem is when the task runs again, the JPA try to insert the id 8 again, generating exception, duplicate primary key.

How can I force JPA to get the id from the table again? Is possible to use a query as strategy?

Comment: Why not just use the sequence for everything?

Comment: I tried, but need too much effort and time to refact the legacy system; It is a 20+ years old desktop system and the database doesn't have auto-increment implemented. That's why I asked about the possibility to use a query as strategy. @TrippKinetics

Comment: I remove the sequence from the task because it was taking too much time, too much read/write operations. Using the sequence, it was taking more than 10 minutes to finishing the task, using the auto strategy, took a few seconds. @TrippKinetics